# Missing export ANDROID_HOME on bash

Tags: android, bash, macos, ionic-framework, sdk

when I run : ionic build android,

problem happens, because de ANDROID_HOME is wrong

ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1

so I set the correct ANDROID_HOME .

$ export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/eltonpering/Library/Android/sdk

$ source ~/.bash_profile

its work.

But, when I close and open a new bash terminal, the problem happens again.

---

$ sudo -V

Sudo version 1.8.17p1

Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.17p1

Sudoers file grammar version 45

Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.17p1

Comment: Add the export line permanently to `.bash_profile`, so that the statement is read on every shell invocation (since `bash_profile` run at start-up of every new shell)

Comment: Yes ! I've done this

Comment: no, but how would it be in **.bashrc** ?